# jQuery #dialog called by multiple Class

Tags: html, jquery, class, button, dialog

I want to integrate a button for each product of my eCommerce in the products listing, where I want show some data of each products, like brand model compatibility.

So I want to realize this with jQuery #dialog but my problem is, when I click on any button, then jQuery opens all dialog for each button.

How I can solve this?

PHP:

```php
$var1 = "ciao";

$var2 = "bau";

$var3 = "miao";
```

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
      $( function() {
        $( ".wrapper" ).dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          title: 'Title Dialog',
          show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
          },
          hide: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 1000
          }
        });
     
        $( ".opener" ).on( "click", function() {
            $( ".wrapper" ).dialog( "open" );
          
        });
      } );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="opener">Button1</button>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <?= $var1 ?>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button class="opener">Button2</button>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <?= $var2 ?>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button class="opener">Button3</button>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <?= $var3 ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `.dialog()` on the element they are moved, so we can't use `.next()`, but you can use the solution below.

```
var i = $(this).index(".opener");
$('.wrapper').eq(i).dialog("open");
```

**DEMO**

```js
$(function() {
  $(".wrapper").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Title Dialog',
    show: {
      effect: "blind",
      duration: 1000
    },
    hide: {
      effect: "explode",
      duration: 1000
    }
  });

  $(".opener").on("click", function() {
    var i = $(this).index(".opener");
    $('.wrapper').eq(i).dialog("open");
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<body>
  <button class="opener">Button1</button>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <?= $var1 ?>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button class="opener">Button2</button>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <?= $var2 ?>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button class="opener">Button3</button>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <?= $var3 ?>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes i know about .next() i tryed before, and i tryed now again but with .next() any button don't work.

Comment: @SalvoUPrincipale Yer my bad, i was a bit to fast. Look at the demo now.